Is there any way to get break-inside to work with "display: contents"?
Bellow is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.
I want the contents of each section to be laid out in the container's grid, but I also want to enforce the there be no page breaks within the contents of a section.
Unfortunately, this does not work, because setting display: contents on section seems to make it behave as though it doesn't exist, including ignoring the effects of break-inside: avoid.


main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

section {
  display: contents;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.foo {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.bar,
.baz {
  grid-column: 2;
}
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="foo">foo</div>
    <div class="bar">bar</div>
    <div class="baz">baz</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="foo">foo</div>
    <div class="bar">bar</div>
    <div class="baz">baz</div>
  </section>
</main>




subgrid might be an option.


main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.foo {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.bar,
.baz {
  grid-column: 2;
}
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="foo">foo</div>
    <div class="bar">bar</div>
    <div class="baz">baz</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="foo">foo</div>
    <div class="bar">bar</div>
    <div class="baz">baz</div>
  </section>
</main>



